# Cloudera cdh cluster docker deployment

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have deployed the cloudera/quickstart image for a single node deployment with docker. However I would like to have a multinode cdh deployment on 4 nodes using docker. I am new to this so anyone who has done the same please let me know how can that be achieved.

Comment: Stay tuned for news about this subject...

Answer (score 1):

Instructions and script now available:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/08/multi-node-clusters-with-cloudera-quickstart-for-docker/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question (running a CDH cluster deployment in docker) but I didn't find tools to do that for the latest CDH releases. That is why I prepared docker images. I hope it will be useful to someone else.

To run a CDH cluster easily, you can use docker-compose. Just create a configuration file based on https://github.com/ipogudin/cloudera-cluster-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml Please, remember that you need to remove build sections from definitions for each service.

Note, you don't need to build images locally (unless you want to customize them). You can use built images from docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/r/ipogudin/cloudera-cluster-gateway/).